# Pass a value type parameter using ref or not, what is faster?

Tags: .net, performance, garbage-collection, clr, pass-by-value

Which of the following methods is going to work out faster?

```
    static void Do(int i)
    {
    }
or
    static void Do(ref int i)
    {
    }
```

Comment: What has your benchmark told you? Is this an actual performance issue you are facing?

Comment: Whichever it is, the difference is unlikely to matter.

Comment: Actually I haven't tested yet. I don't have a profiler on hand

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich, nonsense. If he calls the function a lot it will matter.

Comment: Did you check the IL generated for each one?

Comment: Filburt, yeah, I did. There is nothing unpredictable. Do(int32 i) vs Do(int32& i)

Comment: @Yuriy Faktorovich, yes, I do call a method quite many times. That's why I'm so curious.

Comment: Realize that, without profiling, you'll never really **know** the answer here.  The JIT also is going to potentially optimize this. In a small method, it may even inline it away completely...

Comment: @alga I had to call that method 10^9 times before I was seeing any difference, and even at that point it was barely significant. If you're experiencing a bottleneck, I seriously doubt this is your problem.

Answer (score 2):

In general, I'd say don't worry about it.  If, however, it's really important in this case, profile it and see.  Without measuring, you'll never know which version of a method will truly perform better, especially in your real case, as the JIT may optimize one better than the other, etc.

That being said, at a small level, the answer is really "it depends."  In your case, passing by ref is potentially going to be slower on x64, as its doing a larger copy (the memory location, which is 64bits) vs. just a copy of a 32bit int.  In practical terms, this isn't going to matter at all.

However, if you're dealing with a large value type (struct), then passing by ref *can* be an optimization.  It prevents the full copy of the value type.

This is occasionally a meaningful performance optimization.  For example, many 3D related engines do this for passing vectors or matrices, as these can be a large struct.  For an example, see XNA's [Matrix.Multiply](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb198134.aspx) which uses ref and out parameters instead of copying the matrices by value.  This is more optimized, as the Matrix is 128 bytes, so passing a 4 or 8 byte reference is much more efficient.

Comment: Wouldn't it still be slower to allocate the memory and make a copy of the data than simply passing along a pointer? Granted the time difference is very very small either way.

Comment: @SpectralGhost It's not allocating memory, but rather doing a stack copy.  To pass by ref, you have to copy the memory location - which is still a copy.

Comment: @SpectralGhost Technically, on x64, the copy of the memory location is copying 2x the data as a copy of the int value... since the location is a 64bit address vs. a 32bit int copy.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Rough benchmarks on an x64 machine surprisingly show you're incorrect. Not sure why. It could be a symptom of how the benchmark was constructed.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich Depends a lot on what's happening in the method, too, though, as the JIT can inline the call entirely in some cases, and may not in others...

Comment: @ReedCopsey inside the method I put `var x = i + 1`. It's very consistent, did you want to see the code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any scenario where passing by value is better performing than passing by reference. With the routines you have, you'd have to call them many thousands of times to see a humanly noticeable time difference.